# ASP.NET MVC Web Application - Facing Null Pointer Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting this exception whenever I try to call this redirect link on `Employee` data Image. Any help which could solve this problem is much appreciated.

**My Work:**

`Employee` View `empRecords`:

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;
@model IPagedList<My_Work.Models.Employee>
@{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Detalis"];
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>EmpRecords</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="float:left">
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        @{
            String img64 = (string)Session["userImage"];
            String img64Url = string.Format("data:image/" +
           (string)Session["userImageType"] + ";base64,{0}", img64);
            //imagetype can be e.g. gif, jpeg, png etc.
        }
        <img alt="" src="@img64Url" width="45" height="80"
             class="rounded-circle" />
        <br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Click to Logout", "Logout", "User")
    </div>
    <br />
    <p>

        @Html.Partial("_EmployeeInfo", Model)
    </p>
    <br />
    <div style="float:left">
        <dl>
            <dt>
                @Html.ActionLink("User Last Login:", cookie["Lastlogin"])
            </dt>
            <dd>
                @if (cookie != null)
                {
                    @cookie["Lastlogin"];
                }
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Partial Layout View `_EmployeeInfo`:

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;
@model IPagedList<My_Work.Models.Employee>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().EmployeeID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().ImageURL)
        </th>
        <th>
            Image
        </th>
    </tr>
    @if (Model.Count() == 0)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                No records match search criteria
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Employee", new
            {
                id =
           item.EmployeeID
            }))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>
                       item.FirstName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageURL)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ImageURL))
                         {
                           <a href="/Employee/Details">
                              @*@Url.Content convert the relative path into application absolute path*@
                              <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/" + item.ImageURL)" height="50px" width="50px" />
                           </a>
                         }
                         else
                         {
                            <span>No Image Found!</span>
                         }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
</table>
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("empRecords", new { page,
SearchBy = Request.QueryString["SearchBy"], SearchTerm =
Request.QueryString["SearchTerm"], sortBy =
Request.QueryString["sortBy"] }), new PagedListRenderOptions() {
Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded,
DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true })
```

so, the main problem is that whenever I tried to call this redirect link I faced this error:

**Code:**

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ImageURL))
{
    <a href="/Employee/Details">
        @*@Url.Content convert the relative path into application absolute path*@
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/" + item.ImageURL)" height="50px" width="50px" />
    </a>
}
```

**Error Message:**

[image]

`Employee` Controller functions used for following task:

```cs
public ActionResult empRecords(string SearchBy, string SearchTerm, int? page, string sortBy)
{
    //In case of Invalid user redirect to login
    if (Session["login"] == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
    }
    EmployeeEntity entity = new EmployeeEntity();
    List<Employee> list = entity.GetList(SearchBy,SearchTerm, sortBy);
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Detalis"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        string color = cookie["Lastlogin"];
    }

    return View(list.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));
}

public ActionResult Details(long id)
{
    //In case of Invalid user redirect to login
    if (Session["login"] == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
    }
    EmployeeEntity entity = new EmployeeEntity();
    Employee employee = entity.GetSingleEmployee(id);
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Detalis"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        string color = cookie["Lastlogin"];
    }
    return View(employee);

}
```

`Employee` View `Details`:

```
@model My_Work.Models.Employee
@{
    Layout = null;
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Detalis"];
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Employee Detail</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h4>Employee Detail</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
            </dd>
            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
            </dd>
            <dd>
                @{
                    String img64 = (string)Session["userImage"];
                    String img64Url = string.Format("data:image/" +
                   (string)Session["userImageType"] + ";base64,{0}", img64);
                    //imagetype can be e.g. gif, jpeg, png etc.
                }
                <img alt="" src="@img64Url" width="45" height="80"
                     class="rounded-circle" />
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.EmployeeID
       }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "empRecords")
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing to pass id as parameter when redirect to `/Employee/Details`. Your href URL should be `/Employee/Details/{id}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ISSUE

You get the above error as `id` is the mandatory parameter in `Details` function (action) in `Employee` controller.

```
<a href="/Employee/Details">
    @*@Url.Content convert the relative path into application absolute path*@
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/" + item.ImageURL)" height="50px" width="50px" />
</a>
```

---

### SOLUTION

You have to make sure that `id` must be included in the URL for redirecting to `Employee/Details`.

The URL should be as below:

```
/Employee/Details/{id}
```

**SOLUTION 1:**

```
<a href="/Employee/Details/@item.EmployeeID">
    @*@Url.Content convert the relative path into application absolute path*@
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/" + item.ImageURL)" height="50px" width="50px" />
</a>
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Employee", new { id = item.EmployeeID})">
    @*@Url.Content convert the relative path into application absolute path*@
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/" + item.ImageURL)" height="50px" width="50px" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional note, you can also make the id parameter not mandatory, then It will not give you null pointer exception.  In your code, you will need to add some validation code if you are expecting id parameter can not be null.

```
public ActionResult Details(long? id = null)
{
    // validation code example
    if (!id.HasValue)
    {
        // Redirect or return the appropriate HTTP code here
    }

    //In case of Invalid user redirect to login
    if (Session["login"] == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
    }
    EmployeeEntity entity = new EmployeeEntity();
    Employee employee = entity.GetSingleEmployee(id);
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Detalis"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        string color = cookie["Lastlogin"];
    }
    return View(employee);

}
```

Comment: yeah this looks like a good idea but in my case the id parameter is mandatory.